# How to delete multiple rows in a PostgreSQL database based on string id?

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

So I have the following table:

```
qliu=# select id from api_member;
 id  
-----
 242
 236
 246
 251
 253
 9
 21
 185
 49
 188
```

I want to be able to delete rows with a range of ids with something like the following command:

```
delete from api_member where id between '0' and '10';
```

But it deletes nothing. Also if you were wondering

```
delete from api_member where id between 0 and 10;
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying >= integer
> LINE 1: delete from api_member where id between 0 and 10;
>                                         ^
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Comment: Never store numbers in a `varchar` column. The problem you have, stems directly from that bad design decision.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because your column's `id` is of type `varchar`, not an integer. You can solve this by casting it to `integer`, like this:

```
delete from api_member
where CAST(id as integer) between 0 and 10;
```

If the number of rows is large, this operation may be too slow. Consider changing the type of the `id` column to a numeric type.